# Golang Mongodb insertOne returns empty ID ObjectID("000000000000000000000000")

Tags: go, google-app-engine-golang

I am using Go with MongoDB and creating a New Record but when I convert the insertedID to string it returns ObjectID("000000000000000000000000").

```
client := connect()
db := client.Database("godb")
// fmt.Println(db)

usersCollection := db.Collection("users")

result, err := usersCollection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.D{
    {Key: "title", Value: "The Polyglot Developer Podcast"},
    {Key: "author", Value: "Nic Raboy"},
})

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

newID := result.InsertedID
fmt.Println("InsertOne() newID:", newID)
fmt.Println("InsertOne() newID type:", reflect.TypeOf(newID))

oid, _ := newID.(primitive.ObjectID)
fmt.Println(oid)
```

OUTPUT

```
InsertOne() newID: ObjectID("5e947e7036a5c1587fa4a06e")
InsertOne() newID type: primitive.ObjectID
ObjectID("000000000000000000000000")
```

Comment: Check the result of type assertion: `oid, ok:=...`  and see if `ok` is true. It looks like it is not. Try `oid:=newID.(primitive.ObjectID)`, and the panic msg should tell you what the error is.

Comment: Print `reflect.TypeOf(newID).PkgPath()` and compare to the import in your code. I think you will find that there are two different `primitive` packages in play.

Comment: @CeriseLimón You are magician :) :) :). How did you know the issue? 

I had 2 different packages "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo" and "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo" because of that issue was causing. I removed the github.com package and included the go.mongodb.org package.

Comment: It's clear from the program output that the type assertion failed. If the type assertion failed, then there are two types in play.

Comment: Thanks Cerise. I am very glad to know further about the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You must specify **omitempty** for the ID!

```golang
type User struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
}
```